# Ruby On Rails on Win 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

On win 10, After installing RoR  3.x and Ruby 7.x, and sqlite 3.x, the server will not start from CLI, I am not using Windows Powershell but the CMD window.

Does any part of the install of those packages require Admin window?

Does the "bin/rails server" command  require Admin privileges from CLI.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Not really.
I installed Rails in my Windows Computer, but I needed to install Node and Yarn as well.
I suggest you install WSL for Windows. It's like have Linux install but using Windows. It's faster than Windows and you will have less problems by installing Rails or any other software.
Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/wsl/install

You need to use PowerShell as Administrator and run the command **wsl --install** (see pc requirements)